# I'm an able web developer with advanced knowledge of PHP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and (My)SQL.. where to go from here?

Tags: design, portfolio, working-from-home

To start off with I'm 16 years old, and I do know these languages sufficiently enough to produce a finished product.

I've made a few community based websites in the past, and they were fairly popular (~1k members, 10 - 50 online at one time) and I like those kinds of sites but they don't seem to last long, either because I stop pumping out new content of the users find something else to do.

So I do have experience working with a community, but I want to make something bigger that will open up more opportunities for me in the future. Trouble is there are too many internet giants out there, so any direction I go there will always be a bigger and better site out there right?

If you have any suggestions at all, in terms of a web project, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Hi Ethan, welcome to Freelancing.SE! Unfortunately, this question is not a good fit for a Q&A network site such as the Stack Exchange. Webmasters may be able to help (for programming the sites), or Community Building (for learning to engage a community online), or even just checking out the different chat rooms on SE. If you can [edit] your question to show what problem you have, and what you've tried, we can try to help with a *specific* problem you are having. List type questions are hardly ever encouraged here. Hope this helps!